# What are the differences between object creation using "ClassName.class;" and "new ClassName();" in java?

Tags: java, class, oop

What are the differences between obj1 and obj2 demonstrated below:

```
Class<ClassName>  obj1 = ClassName.class;

ClassName obj2 = new ClassName();
```

Comment: For starters, they are different types.

Comment: Yes, I am newbie, maybe both of them are equal; I am curious about whether their type is equal, which one is better in terms of performance,  whether obj1 calls the constructor or not

Comment: No they are not equal.  The difference is that they mean very different things.  This is not a performance issue at all.  Read Mureinik's answer.

Comment: `Class<ClassName>` is basically just metadata of the class, nothing you would work with (in non-advanced use-cases). The second line calls the constructor and returns an object you can work with

Comment: @Denisa But `obj` would then be an instance of `Class`, not an instance of `AnnotationExample`. A `Class` object is used to *describe* a class at runtime, and is part of the Reflection API of Java. If you don't understand the difference, i.e. the difference between data and meta-data, then doing reflection logic is way beyond your current level, and you should come back to learn about reflection at a later time. Reflection is an advanced topic.

Answer (score 4):

`obj2` is an instance of the `ClassName` class. `obj1` is an instance of [`java.lang.Class`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) the represents the `ClassName` class.

Comment: Maybe pointing out that `obj2.getClass()` also returns `obj1` might make it clearer too.

Comment: The Class is like a stencil or template. With that stencil you can create separate objects, using the `new` keyword. Everything that's tagged with the `static` keyword clings to the stencil, while everything else clings to the created objects. Calling `obj.getClass()` simply returns the stencil that was used to create the object.

Comment: Thank you all friends, it is getting clearer